# How to obtain text from a String variable?

Tags: java, string

```
String s = System.lineSeparator();
System.out.println(s);
```

I try to obtain text from variable `s`, but why is there no text in variable `s` ?

Comment: Oddly enough, `System.lineSeparator()` returns a line separator.  Surprised me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code on your system

```
for(byte b : System.lineSeparator().getBytes()){
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

It will print either

```
10
```

OR

```
13
10
```

Here I print the ascii code for whatever I got from `System.lineSeparator()`.
ascii code for `\n` is 10 and for `\r` is 13.

It is also given in documentation of `System.lineSeparator()`

> On UNIX systems, it returns "\n"; on Microsoft Windows systems it returns "\r\n".

So the point is you didn't see any output because if you try to print `\r` or `\n` because `\r` represents line feed and `\n` represents next line. And you cannot see them on console. But they will have their effects in strings.

Comment: Whether have a way to print \r\n or \n ?

Answer (score 0):

The `System.lineSeparator();` returns a string that the system uses to generally separate lines in, say for example, an input from the Standard Input.

This is generally a new line character and so when you print it in your program, you will not "See" it as is.

Try using this:

```
String s = System.lineSeparator();
System.out.println("~~" + s + "~~");
```

This will help you distinguish the output. You should see something like this:

```
~~
~~
```

This output would indicate the the new line character is separating the `~~` characters in your print statement.

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

System.lineSeperator() will mostly return "\r\n", so when you sysout it actualy prints a new line.